# CSS content slider bullet preview

Tags: html, css

I have code below for a content slider using HTML and CSS only. How do I make it so when I hover on one of the 3 bullets at the bottom a little preview image of the slide appears right above the bullet. Something like this: http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider
Anything helps, thanks.

```css
.pic{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">› </label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">› </label>

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">●</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">●</label> </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">●</label> </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see at the provided link is a complete independent slider inside the main slider. But here is the simple one. Add an element next to each label inside the lis. Then define an absolute position for them and set the height to zero.

Finally, add the hover css and add transition to it.

```css
.pic{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.carousel {
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    widht:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-inner {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-open:checked + .carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 100;
    background-color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:335px;
}

.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    padding-top:10px;
    text-align:center;
}

.carousel-control {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    color:#008c6c;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    font-size: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    -ms-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 10;
}

.carousel-control.prev {
    left: 2%;
}

.carousel-control.next {
    right: 2%;
}

.carousel-control:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    color: #008c6c;
}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3{
    display: block;
}

.carousel-indicators {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    position: relative; /*You are required to do this*/
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview {
    position: absolute;
    width: 108px;
    top: -0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -52px;
    height:0px;
    transition:0.5s all;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.carousel-indicators .carousel-preview img {
    max-width:100px;
    max-height:50px;
    padding: 2px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #ccc;
}
.carousel-indicators li:hover .carousel-preview {
    height:54px;
    top:-50px;
}
.carousel-bullet {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 35px;
}

.carousel-bullet:hover {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.HRConnectImage
{width:375px;
padding-top:50px;
display:inline-block;}

#carousel-1:checked ~ .control-1 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(1) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-2:checked ~ .control-2 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(2) .carousel-bullet,
#carousel-3:checked ~ .control-3 ~ .carousel-indicators li:nth-child(3) .carousel-bullet{
    color: #008c6c;
}

#title {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 27px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33), -1px 0px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}

#p
{
text-align:center;
font-weight:bold;}
```

```html
<div class="carousel"> 
   <div class="carousel-inner"> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-1" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true" Checked/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-2" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
  <img class="pic" src="">
      </div> 
      <input name="carousel" class="carousel-open" id="carousel-3" aria-hidden="true" type="radio" hidden="true"/> 
      <div class="carousel-item"> 
<img class="pic" src="">
      </div>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-1" for="carousel-3">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-1" for="carousel-2">› </label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-2" for="carousel-1">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-2" for="carousel-3">›</label>
      <label class="carousel-control prev control-3" for="carousel-2">‹</label>
      <label class="carousel-control next control-3" for="carousel-1">› </label>

      <ol class="carousel-indicators"> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-1">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb1.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-2">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb3.jpg" />
            </div>
         <li> 
            <label class="carousel-bullet" for="carousel-3">●</label> 
            <div class="carousel-preview">
              <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/thumb2.jpg" />
            </div>
         </li> 

      </ol> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: How do I get it so when I hover on the image, then hover off the preview instantly goes away instead of going down to hide?

Comment: Its working fine, but when you hover off there is a slight transition hiding the preview image, correct?

Comment: Yes. You want to remove it?

Comment: Only when You hover off, yes. Just so it goes away instantly. I want it to stay when you hover on though.

Comment: I am afraid you might not be able to do it without employing jQuery. This method is faster because it uses CSS properties but it has its own drawbacks.

Comment: Can you do with vanilla JavaScript?

Comment: I am not familiar with. If you search it, you should be able.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141920/discussion-between-ahbagheri-and-display-name).